# Getting connection time out error for local repository

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, repository

As we know that Ubuntu 12.10(Quantal) is at EOL. So all the package repositories are moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.

I can access all the packages from that url.

Now I have set up some packages on my private server. For building my local repository I referred following links
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CreateAuthenticatedReposito and
http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/06/27/setting-up-a-simple-ubuntu-apt-repository/

Also made the changes in the **sources.list** file.

But when I do sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get install my_package then I get following error

```
Could not connect to XXXXX.XXXX.com. - connect (110: Connection timed out)
```

How can I resolve this error. Is there port issue (like I have to open port or is there any firewall issue) or is there any other issue.